# Flutter : trying to fetch api data but getting this error => type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'FutureOr<Map<String, dynamic>>'

Tags: flutter, dart

I am making a rest call and getting this data in this format

```
"{\r\n "userAlreadyExists\": false,\r\n "fullName\": null,\r\n "email\": {\r\n   "value\":"sdevpura5@gmail.com\\t\",\r\n   "error\":"'Email' is not in the correct format.\"\r\n  },\r\n "password\": null,\r\n "day\": null,\r\n "month\": null,\r\n "year\": null,\r\n "birthDate\": null,\r\n "invalidData\": true,\r\n "somethingWentWrong\": false,\r\n "error\": null\r\n}"
```

then I am trying to map this data into a JSON object by using this function

```
json.decode(newString);
```

but getting an error:

> type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'FutureOr<Map<String,
> dynamic>>'

[image]

Can anyone please help me on this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I think you're doing something like:

```
String response = json.decode(newString);
```

which is an error. You should rather do:

```
Map<String, dynamic> response = json.decode(newString);
```

Comment: just tried and now getting this error: type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, dynamic>'

Comment: yes. i used this line
Map<String, dynamic> response = await json.decode(newString);

Comment: @sourabhdevpura Ahh I used `await`, please check out the updated code now.

Comment: Still getting the same error and also I just uploaded a screenshot